# PredicateBuilder methods clarification

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees, linqpad, predicatebuilder

I looked through [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) sources and its' implementation makes me curious. Let's look at Or method implementation:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
```

Why does it Invoke new lambda instead of just using OrElse for predicate body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's a typing issue: `Expression.OrElse` returns a plain Expression, not an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

Comment: Good point, may be it is just a workaround to get rid off expression type casting (to be able to access to Body property). But it makes expression more difficult...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure either, but I think the issue is ensuring that as each expression `Func<T,bool>` is chained, the parameter, which is an instance of *T*, is always the same instance for each expression.

In other words, for:

```
(t1 => t1>5).And(t2 => t2.Color == Blue)
```

we assume t1 and t2 are referentially equal, but the InvocationExpression ensures they are by essentially saying: "create a new expression that invokes *expr2* with the parameter from *expr1*".

See also [PredicateBuilder Revisited](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2010/07/20/predicatebuilder-revisited) where the author, a contributor to Mono, really explicitly checks for the reference equality of the parameter.